# VBA nested "for" and "if"

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I am doing nested `if`  within loops, which is basically:

```
1:  For i = 1 To n
    If condition1 Then
2:     For j = 1 To m
           If condition2 Then
3:            For k = 1 To p
                  If condition3 Then
                     statement1
                  End If
              Next k
           End If
        Next j
    End If
    Next i
```

After `statement1`, I would like to `Exit` the loop `2` and `3` and go directly to `1`.

However if I use `Exit For` this will only exit `3`. If I put a line before `1`, and then use `GoTo` to refer to it, it will not work either because the program has to start with `1`.

Comment: maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/goto-statement or k = p + 1 and j = m + 1

Comment: Hi @Slai this could be useful, making the program to go to different places when different conditions are met. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap the code you need to exit from into dummy `Do ... Loop Until True` block, use `Exit Do` for immediate exit.

Comment: @omegastripes Thanks this is a smart way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a helper `Boolean` variable to mark when to exit loop 2, as follows

```
Dim exitLoop2 As Boolean

For i = 1 To n
    If condition1 Then
        exitLoop2 = False ' set it to false at the beginning of any loop 2
        For j = 1 To m
            If condition2 Then
                For k = 1 To p
                    If condition3 Then
                        exitLoop2 = True ' this will make you exit loop 2 once out of loop 3
                        Exit For ' this will exit loop 3
                    'statement1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If exitLoop2 Then Exit For ' exit loop 2 if needed
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you it's a great suggestion to add a Boolean variable!

Answer (score 1):

There is more elegant way. Wrap the code you need to exit from into dummy `Do ... Loop Until True` block, then use `Exit Do` for immediate exit.

```vb
For i = 1 To n
    Do
        If condition1 Then
           For j = 1 To m
               If condition2 Then
                  For k = 1 To p
                      If condition3 Then
                         statement1
                         Exit Do
                      End If
                  Next k
               End If
            Next j
        End If
    Loop Until True
Next i
```